# Cannot find/understand how to use the New Input System in Unity for my PlayerController script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this player controller script for a 2D top down game
It uses the old input system but I want to use the newer one so that my game can support several input types (and also because I want to learn how to use the new input system)

I read the documentation on unity but still can't understand, I found this document https://gamedevbeginner.com/input-in-unity-made-easy-complete-guide-to-the-new-system/#input_system_explained but for the love of god I still cannot understand what the hell I should do and how to do it

I set up the Control Schemes (Keyboard & Mouse and Controller), The Action Maps (Fighting/Moving), the actions(Go up,down,right and left)
[Here is a screenshot of the controls I set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPjjN.png)

I'm still kinda new to Unity and programming, if someone could help me it would be appreciated
This is all incredibly confusing

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float moveSpeed = 5;
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform movePoint;
    [SerializeField]
    private LayerMask obstacleMask;

    private void Awake()
    {
        //remove the move point from the player cause I only did that for the sake of organization
        movePoint.parent = null;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, movePoint.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, movePoint.position) <= .5f)
        {

            if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")) == 1)
            {
                if (!Physics2D.OverlapCircle(movePoint.position + new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f), .2f, obstacleMask))
                {
                    movePoint.position += new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
                }

            }
            else if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")) == 1)
            {
                if (!Physics2D.OverlapCircle(movePoint.position + new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"), 0f), .2f, obstacleMask))
                {
                    movePoint.position += new Vector3(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"), 0f);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error or it is simply not working?

Comment: @HardykMahendru well until now OP is using `Input` from the "old" input system ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have setup the Control Schemes almost correctly, you need to change the Action Type to `Value` and Control Type to `Vector2` or `Stick`, because you are getting two axes (up/down and left/right), like this:

[image]

Then you need to setup your scheme in the game, you need to add a `Player Input` component and select your Control Scheme:

[image]

Finally from your code you can access all the actions and action maps of your Control Scheme, in this case instead of reading a Horizontal and a Vertical axis you read them both like this:

```
InputActionAsset actions;

void Awake() {
    // Retrieve the action asset
    actions = GetComponent<PlayerInput>().actions;
}

void Update() {
    // Retrieve the current movement input (horizontal, vertical)
    // You can save this action in a variable in the Awake too if you plan to use it multiple times (like during each Update)
    Vector2 movement = actions.FindAction("Movement").ReadValue<Vector2>();

    // Check if we have horizontal movement
    if(movement.x != 0f){
        // Do stuff
    }

    // Check if we have vertical movement
    if(movement.y != 0f){
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

**Final note:** I would avoid naming the Maps or Actions with a slash (/) in it, because you can retrieve actions from different maps like `actions.FindAction("Music_Fight/Movement")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Input class while using the new input system.
you should define input action in your input actions and use it to move your object.

In your asset folder in unity, right-click => Create => input actions.
then define some action for move like this picture:

[image]

then save it. Click on it and in inspector enable "Generate C# class".
then in your code something like this:

```
private void Awake()
{
    InputActions playerInput = new InputActions();
    playerInput.GamePlayPlayer.Move.performed += context => MoveInput(context);
    playerInput.Enable();
}

private void MoveInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    Vector2 input = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    moveInputData = new Vector3(input.x, 0, input.y);
}
void Update()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, movePoint.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(moveInputData == Vector3.Zero)
        return;
        
    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, movePoint.position) <= .5f)
    {
        if (!Physics2D.OverlapCircle(movePoint.position + moveInputData, .2f, obstacleMask))
        {
            movePoint.position += moveInputData;
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't test it, but I think it should be fine.